# Ruby on Rails Scaffold not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, scaffold

I have created a scaffold to create a weekly log with this migration:

```
class CreateLoggs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :loggs do |t|
    t.string :Name
    t.string :Date
    t.string :Time
    t.text :WhatsGoneWellThisWeek?
    t.text :WhatsNotGoneWellThisWeek?
    t.text :LearntAnythingNew?
    t.text :WhatWouldYouLikeToImprove?
    t.text :AnythingElse?

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

I assumed that t.text will take more characters. However, after writing a paragraph in each of the text field, it outputted empty, apart from the string types. I then changed everything to string but that didn’t work either, in fact it didn't even allow me to type even 2 or 3 letters. I want the text types to be able to take a paragraph each in the form. My only guess is maybe the headings I created are too long? (btw I also tried this like What_would_you_like_to_improve? ) but still had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CreateLoggs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :loggs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :date
      t.string :time
      t.text :whats_gone_well_this_week
      t.text :whats_not_gone_well_this_week
      t.text :learnt_anything_new
      t.text :what_would_you_like_to_improve
      t.text :anything_else
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

end
```